# Cross-correlation with Spearman's method

Tags: r, correlation, cross-correlation

I am trying to calculate the cross-correlation between two time series. I know that ccf in R base can slove this problem and it uses Pearson's correlation method. My question is: How can I calculate cross-correlation with Spearman's method? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an approximation you could just rank each of your time series and do a pearson correlation on the ranked time series.